# Why doesn't the output value show when the terms are appropiate

Tags: python, input, location

I want it to print a message and change some values when the mario.location values are equal to the coin.location values in python. Why isn't it doing that? It is just printing the regular input. Which is just printing the location values.

```
class mario:
  x_location = 0 
  y_location = 0 
  z_location = 0 
  health = 3


class coin:
  x = 1
  y = 0 
  z = 1 

rules = [mario.x_location == coin.x, 
  mario.y_location == coin.y, 
  mario.z_location == coin.z]

start = input('say yes: ').lower() 
while start == 'yes':
  command = input('').lower()
  if command == 'w':
    mario.x_location += 1 
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location)

  elif command == 's':
    mario.x_location -= 1
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location)

  elif command == 'a':
    mario.z_location -= 1 
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location) 

  elif command == 'd':
    mario.z_location += 1 
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location)

  elif all(rules):
    if mario.health == 3:
      print('you collected a coin')
      print('health: ', mario.health)
    elif mario.health < 3:
      print('You collected a coin and healed')
      mario.health += 1
      print('Health: ', mario.health)
```

Comment: As an aside, class names should follow the `CamelCase` style.

Answer (score 0):

You are only comparing the values one single time before even starting the while loop. You should be comparing the values every iteration, after a command is chosen.

```
while start == 'yes':
  command = input('').lower()
  if command == 'w':
    mario.x_location += 1 
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location)

  elif command == 's':
    mario.x_location -= 1
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location)

  elif command == 'a':
    mario.z_location -= 1 
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location) 

  elif command == 'd':
    mario.z_location += 1 
    print(mario.x_location, mario.y_location, mario.z_location)

  rules = [mario.x_location == coin.x, 
  mario.y_location == coin.y, 
  mario.z_location == coin.z]

  if all(rules):
    if mario.health == 3:
      print('you collected a coin')
      print('health: ', mario.health)
    elif mario.health < 3:
      print('You collected a coin and healed')
      mario.health += 1
      print('Health: ', mario.health)
```

Sample run:

```
say yes: yes
w
1 0 0
a
1 0 -1
d
1 0 0
d
1 0 1
you collected a coin
health:  3
```